# Node + Express: unhandled ECONNRESET error

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I have a Node + Express server running with forever on Digital Ocean. Every day or so the server throws an uncaught error and restarts. The server cycles on the same operation continuously but only throws the error randomly.

I have written error handlers in the code for all connections the server is making.

The node output:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: read ECONNRESET
at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
at Pipe.onread (net.js:558:19)
```

I tried catching the error with:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.error(err.stack);
});
```

But that didn't work. I am not using socket connections and there are no front-end clients connecting to this server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on other answers on Stackoverflow, I added these handlers:

```
app.listen(3137, 'localhost', function() {
    console.log("3137 ~ ~");
}).on('error', function(err){
    console.log('on error handler');
    console.log(err);
});


process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    console.log('process.on handler');
    console.log(err);
});
```

Hopefully either one catches the error...